# Moment JS - check if a date is today or in the future

Tags: momentjs

I am trying to use `momentjs` to check if a given date is today or in the future.

This is what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var SpecialToDate = '31/01/2014'; // DD/MM/YYYY

var SpecialTo = moment(SpecialToDate, "DD/MM/YYYY");
if (moment().diff(SpecialTo) > 0) {
    alert('date is today or in future');
} else {
    alert('date is in the past');
}

</script>
```

The code is evaluating my date (31st of Jan 2014) as a date in past.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 258, accepted):

After reading the documentation: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/, you have to consider the `diff` function like a minus operator.

```
                   // today < future (31/01/2014)
today.diff(future) // today - future < 0
future.diff(today) // future - today > 0
```

Therefore, you have to **reverse** your condition.

If you want to check that all is fine, you can add an extra parameter to the function:

```
moment().diff(SpecialTo, 'days') // -8 (days)
```

Comment: this won't work if it's a different day but the difference is less than 24 hours

Comment: Working, regardless if time difference is less than 24 hours.

Comment: Not working for me. If day is +1 in future moment().diff(SpecialTo, 'days') gives me -0 (negative zero)

Comment: Today doesn't mean in next 24 hours. isSame is good solution.

Comment: SpecialToDate.isBefore()

Comment: `moment().diff(SpecialToDate)` will directly give the difference in milliseconds. `'days'` is not needed. This will work for all scenarios. SpecialToDate can be `'2018-10-26 00:00:00'` for an example.

Answer (score 386):

You can use the `isSame` function:

```
var iscurrentDate = startTime.isSame(new Date(), "day");
if(iscurrentDate) {

}
```

Comment: does this match year and month too?

Comment: It's must match year and month. moment('2010-01-01').isSame('2011-01-01', 'month'); // false, different year
moment('2010-01-01').isSame('2010-02-01', 'day');   // false, different month

Comment: This doesn't even answer the OP's question... "today OR IN THE FUTURE", and what is `startTime`? Date object don't have a `isSame` method...

Comment: @Sharcoux This question is about momentjs, so clearly it is a moment object.

Answer (score 230):

Since no one seems to have mentioned it yet, the simplest way to check if a Moment date object is in the past:

```
momentObj.isBefore()
```

Or in the future:

```
momentObj.isAfter()
```

Just leave the args blank -- that'll default to now.

There's also [`isSameOrAfter`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same-or-after/) and [`isSameOrBefore`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same-or-before/).

N.B. this factors in time. If you only care about the day, see [Dipendu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45751816/65387).

Comment: The docs explain that this is undefined behaviour, so you should not do this: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-before/

Comment: @Dancrumb Read it again. "If nothing is passed to moment#isBefore, it will default to the current time." The `momentObj` in my example is an instance of a moment date. The docs are specifically talking about creating a new instance (current time) and then checking if it is in the past, in one statement. I'm **not** suggesting you do `moment().isBefore()` which is utterly pointless -- why would you check if *now* is in the past (or future)?

Comment: This is the best answer in my opinion, short, precise and effective.

Answer (score 188):

```
// Returns true if it is today or false if it's not
moment(SpecialToDate).isSame(moment(), 'day');
```

Answer (score 94):

You can use the `isAfter()` query function of momentjs:

Check if a moment is after another moment.

```
moment('2010-10-20').isAfter('2010-10-19'); // true
```

If you want to limit the granularity to a unit other than milliseconds, pass the units as the second parameter.

```
moment('2010-10-20').isAfter('2010-01-01', 'year'); // false

moment('2010-10-20').isAfter('2009-12-31', 'year'); // true
```

http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-after/

Comment: The constructor that takes a date string is deprecated.

Comment: @VahidAmiri The [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/) don't mention this. They do however suggest we use [string + format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) constructor if we don't use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). So unless one is using some weird date formats it is OK to use just a string.

Answer (score 40):

**Update**

```js
moment().isSame('2010-02-01', 'day'); // Return true if we are the 2010-02-01
```

I have since found the [**isSame**](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/05-query/02-is-same/) function, which in I believe is the correct function to use for figuring out if a date is today.

**Original answer**

Just in case someone else needs this, just do this:

```
const isToday = moment(0, "HH").diff(date, "days") == 0;
```

or if you want a function:

```
isToday = date => moment(0,"HH").diff(date, "days") == 0;
```

Where **date** is the date you want to check for.

**Explanation**

`moment(0, "HH")` returns today's day at midnight.

`date1.diff(date2, "days")` returns the number of days between the date1 and date2.

Answer (score 34):

invert isBefore method of moment to check if a date is same as today or in future like this:

```
!moment(yourDate).isBefore(moment(), "day");
```

Comment: easy and superb

Answer (score 9):

**To check if it is today**:

If we compare two dates which contain also the time information `isSame` will obviously fail. `diff` will fail in case that the two dates span over the new day:

```
var date1 = moment("01.01.2016 23:59:00", "DD.MM.YYYY HH.mm.ss");
var date2 = moment("02.01.2016 00:01:00", "DD.MM.YYYY HH.mm.ss");
var diff = date2.diff(date1); // 2seconds
```

I think the best way, even if it is not quick and short, is the following:

```
var isSame = date1.date() == date2.date() && date1.month() == date2.month() && date1.year() == date2.year()
```

**To check if it is in the future**:

As suggested also by other users, the `diff` method works.

```
var isFuture = now.diff(anotherDate) < 0
```

Answer (score 8):

If you only need to know which one is bigger, you can also compare them directly:

```
var SpecialToDate = '31/01/2014'; // DD/MM/YYYY

var SpecialTo = moment(SpecialToDate, "DD/MM/YYYY");
if (moment() > SpecialTo) {
    alert('date is today or in future');
} else {
    alert('date is in the past');
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

Use the simplest one to check for future date

```
if(moment().diff(yourDate) >=  0)
     alert ("Past or current date");
else
     alert("It is a future date");
```

Answer (score 5):

I wrote functions that check if a date of Moment type is a Day that Passed or not,  as functional and self-descriptive functions.
Maybe it is could to help someone.

```js
function isItBeforeToday(MomentDate: Moment) {
  return MomentDate.diff(moment(0, 'HH')) < 0;
}

function isItAfterToday(MomentDate: Moment) {
  return MomentDate.diff(moment(0, 'HH')) > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

if firstDate is same or after(future) secondDate **return true** else return false. Toda is firstDate = new Date();

```
  static isFirstDateSameOrAfterSecondDate(firstDate: Date, secondDate: Date): boolean {
    var date1 = moment(firstDate);
    var date2 = moment(secondDate);
    if(date1 && date2){
      return date1.isSameOrBefore(date2,'day');
    }
    return false;
  }
```

There is isSame, isBefore and isAfter for day compare moment example;

```
  static isFirstDateSameSecondDate(firstDate: Date, secondDate: Date): boolean {
    var date1 = moment(firstDate);
    var date2 = moment(secondDate);
    if (date1 && date2) {
      return date1.isSame(date2,'day');
    }
    return false;
  }

  static isFirstDateAfterSecondDate(firstDate: Date, secondDate: Date): boolean {
    var date1 = moment(firstDate);
    var date2 = moment(secondDate);
    if(date1 && date2){
      return date1.isAfter(date2,'day');
    }
    return false;
  }

  static isFirstDateBeforeSecondDate(firstDate: Date, secondDate: Date): boolean {
    var date1 = moment(firstDate);
    var date2 = moment(secondDate);
    if(date1 && date2){
      return date1.isBefore(date2,'day');
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Select yesterday to check past days or not with help of `moment().subtract(1, "day");`

Reference:- http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/

```js
function myFunction() {
  var yesterday = moment().subtract(1, "day").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
  var SpecialToDate = document.getElementById("theDate").value;

  if (moment(SpecialToDate, "YYYY-MM-DD", true).isAfter(yesterday)) {
    alert("date is today or in future");
    console.log("date is today or in future");
  } else {
    alert("date is in the past");
    console.log("date is in the past");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<input type="date" id="theDate" onchange="myFunction()">
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function isTodayOrFuture(date){
  date = stripTime(date);
  return date.diff(stripTime(moment.now())) >= 0;
}

function stripTime(date){
  date = moment(date);
  date.hours(0);
  date.minutes(0);
  date.seconds(0);
  date.milliseconds(0);
  return date;
}
```

And then just use it line this :

```
isTodayOrFuture(YOUR_TEST_DATE_HERE)
```

Answer (score 2):

If we want difference without the time you can get the date different (only date without time) like below, using moment's format.

As, I was facing issue with the difference while doing ;

```
moment().diff([YOUR DATE])
```

So, came up with following;

`const dateValidate = moment(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD')).diff(moment([YOUR SELECTED DATE HERE]).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))`

```
IF dateValidate > 0 
   //it's past day
else
   //it's current or future
```

Please feel free to comment if there's anything to improve on.

Thanks,

Comment: Please review [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code-only answers are discouraged because they do not explain how they resolve the issue. You should update your answer to ***explain what this does and how it improves on the many answers this question already has***.

Answer (score 0):

i wanted it for something else but eventually found a trick which you can try

`somedate.calendar(compareDate, { sameDay: '[Today]'})=='Today'`

```js
var d = moment();
 var today = moment();
 
 console.log("Usign today's date, is Date is Today? ",d.calendar(today, {
    sameDay: '[Today]'})=='Today');
    
 var someRondomDate = moment("2012/07/13","YYYY/MM/DD");
 
 console.log("Usign Some Random Date, is Today ?",someRondomDate.calendar(today, {
    sameDay: '[Today]'})=='Today');
    
  
 var anotherRandomDate =  moment("2012/07/13","YYYY/MM/DD");
 
 console.log("Two Random Date are same date ? ",someRondomDate.calendar(anotherRandomDate, {
    sameDay: '[Today]'})=='Today');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

check with following:

```
let isContinue = moment().diff('2020-04-04T20:06:11+05:30')/1000
```

it is returning in seconds..

If will check as 2 mins condition then

```
if (isContinue < 120) {
  ..To check otp details or further logic
} else {
   // otp is getting invalid
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest answer will be:

```
const firstDate = moment('2020/10/14'); // the date to be checked
const secondDate = moment('2020/10/15'); // the date to be checked

firstDate.startOf('day').diff(secondDate.startOf('day'), 'days'); // result = -1
secondDate.startOf('day').diff(firstDate.startOf('day'), 'days'); // result = 1
```

It will check with the midnight value and will return an accurate result. It will work also when time diff between two dates is less than 24 hours also.