# How to delay script run using moment js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to execute a script at a specific time. How do I get something like this to work?

```
var future = moment().add('1', 'm').format()
if (moment().format() == future) {console.log('Whatsapp')}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21284312/moment-js-check-if-a-date-is-today-or-in-the-future

Answer (score 0):

Get the time difference between now and the specific time in the future. Set a timeout:

```js
const future = moment().add('5', 's');
const now = moment();
setTimeout(() => { console.log('Whatsapp'); }, future.diff(now));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```